# iOS - how to NSLog just one time when using scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, nslog

In the method `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender` I tried to `NSLog`an integer and it `NSLog` the integer more than one time when I scroll.

Is there's any way to NSLog the integer just one time?

Comment: Keep a flag to remember if you've already logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` to get only when the scroll starts. It is not called constantly like `scrollViewDidScroll:` is.

Here are the other UIScrollViewDelegate methods if you are interested:

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillBeginDragging: